# How can I add uncaughtExceptionHandler function in BroadcastReceiver app?

Tags: android

I know I can add the following code to onCreate of Activity to handle uncaughtException.
but in my BroadcastReceiver app, I have no UI, and no Activity, how can I do?

```
final UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {        
        //TODO Handle Exception
        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this code into the constructor of your BroadcastReceiver

```
public MyBroadcastReceiver() {
    final UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH = Thread
            .getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            // TODO Handle Exception
            defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        }
    });
}
```